# Web API in Area and Inversion of Control Constructor References

Tags: asp.net, inversion-of-control, asp.net-web-api

I've setup web APIs in an area of an MVC web site.  I've followed [this post](http://netmvc.blogspot.be/2012/06/aspnet-mvc-4-webapi-support-areas-in.html) that sets up a custom DefaultHttpControllerSelector instance for serving up related types.  However, I have a problem whereby the controllers found in the area need to be dynamically constructed.  It does not seem the custom controller activator I created to do this for the MVC site is being used for Web API.  What object can I use to set this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can plugin in your logic through `IHttpControllerActivator`

```
public interface IHttpControllerActivator
{
    IHttpController Create(
        HttpRequestMessage request,
        HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor,
        Type controllerType);
}
```

Mark Seemann has a couple of great posts about DI in Web API using this interface:

http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/09/28/DependencyInjectionAndLifetimeManagementWithASPNETWebAPI.aspx
 http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/10/03/DependencyInjectionInASPNETWebAPIWithCastleWindsor.aspx